# Implement ManualResetEvent and AutoResetEvent

Tags: qt

How to implement ManualResetEvent and AutoResetEvent in Qt?

Comment: These are the terms in .NET framework. Next time you'd get better luck by reformulating your questions in non-framework specific terms, e.g. "How to notify a waiting thread that an event has occurred". The world is not only .NET, you know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implemented using QWaitCondition.